# Running application not showed in list as red points

Tags: menu

I have a problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. It happend sometimes with different applications. I see a red point for each running window of an application in list of vertical menu. But, sometimes there is a running application that not showing as a red point in list for several hours. Then can be showing correctly again.

[image: how it looks like]

Note: Notepad and Chromium added to Favorites list, so their icons always in list.